# Is there a way to quick print and output a result in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was wondering if there was a way of printing a Python calculation result in a single line of code. I have an old memory of something like that being possible but I can't recall. It worked and look similar to this:

```
mean = sum/n //print # saving the calculation then quick printing the output.
# or
print( mean = sum/n ) # with mean being saved as a variable but I am more looking for something like on the above.
```

instead of the usual way which takes two lines

```
mean = sum/n
print(mean)
```

Thanks a lot if there is any way.

Comment: What's wrong with the two lines? Don't try to combine the two, it only hurts readability.

Comment: Well sometimes I just want to make a quick output without actually embed it in the code as if it was part of it. Just meant to be an output that I write then remove straight away.

Comment: Then why do you need to assign it to a variable? Why not `print(sum/n)`?

Comment: Well basically that's to monitor the different, let say milestones, in a set of code. In that case, printing some calculation by just adding a `// print` command takes much lesser time overall than having to add a newline, then copy/paste the formula or variable I wish to output. That is not a big deal to do so of course. I was just asking if there was a way of doing that easily. Apparently not, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.8 you can utilize the walrus operator:

```
print(mean := sum/n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's simpler than you think.

`mean = sum/n; print(mean)`

```
def update_print(val):
   print(val)
   return val

mean = update_print(sum/n)
```

There is a python-walrus module which supports walrus operation since python 3.3.

https://pypi.org/project/python-walrus/